# Call url in Android. No need to wait for any response

Tags: php, android, xampp

In my project I need to call a URL .

This urls, looks like: http://myip:80/increaseCounter.php

I got a Xampp (MAC) with mysql. The functionallity of increaseCounter.php, is retrive the value from the table, increase it in 1, and update it.
The url I tested in localhost, pointing from another device via Chrome, and works perfect.

But know I'm trying to do just a call to this link in Android, I don't need to recover any data or similar, just call it.

I tried to do:

```
private void trackUrl(String href) {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(href);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("APP", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

But is no working.No connection log in xampp, and the data in mysql ,is not updated.

=======

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="my.aswsome.app"
    android:versionCode="15">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
.....
```

Comment: Share manifest. And share error message.

Comment: @AhmadAghazadeh Manifest has Internet Connection permission, because, this app is working with it from long time ago., And there is no error log. :/

Comment: What if you do `int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code==200){ Log.i("TAG","success") }` instead of `con.connect();`

Comment: @Denny with `urlConnection.getResponseCode();` worked perfectly. I still don't understand what the hell is going, but worked. I f you want, do the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Posted it as an answer with a small explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
if(code==200){ 
    Log.i("TAG","success");
}
```

instead of `con.connect();`

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect()
`.connect();` **only** opens the connect but does nothing after. So by doing `.getResponseCode()` you actually do a request.

Answer (score 0):

```
     you can put url directly that type

    URL url = new URL("http://myip:80/increaseCounter.php");

   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```